# Valor Null em Datas com PHP e XML

Tags: php, html, xml, data, strtotime

Ola, boa noite estou com o seguinte problema:

Tenho um arquivo em XML que é lido por uma Table em PHP, existe um campo de data que pode ser vazio ou não, quando a tem data está lendo ok, porem quando é vazio o ECHO mostra a data de hoje quando era para mostrar a célula vazia (sem data):

Segue um exemplo em que um capo data é Vazio (LastLogonDate):

```
<user>
<CanonicalName>MeuDominio/Usuario/Marcos Silva</CanonicalName>
<Company>MinhaEmpresa</Company>
<Created>02/26/2022 14:27:28</Created>
<Department>TI</Department>
<DisplayName>Marcos Silva</DisplayName>
<DistinguishedName>CN=Marcos Silva,OU=Usuario,DC=>MeuDominio,DC=com</DistinguishedName>
<Enabled>True</Enabled>
<GivenName>Marcos</GivenName>
<LastLogonDate>
</LastLogonDate>
<Mail>marcos.silva@>MeuDominio.com</Mail>
<Name>Marcos Silva</Name>
<ObjectClass>user</ObjectClass>
<ObjectGUID>202869f9-46fe-47da-835a-fc2d5a91169f</ObjectGUID>
<PasswordLastSet>
</PasswordLastSet>
<SamAccountName>marcos.siva</SamAccountName>
<SID>S-1-5-21-2066650521-2777454645-1509904790-187002</SID>
<Surname>Silva</Surname>
<Title>
</Title>
<UserPrincipalName>marcos.silva@>MeuDominio.com</UserPrincipalName>
```

A parte do PHP que mostra a data (o  é só para configurar o sort caso alguém pergunte):

```
<td><span><?php echo date('Ymd', strtotime($user->LastLogonDate)); ?></span><?php echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($user->LastLogonDate)); ?></td>
```

Desde já agradeço

Answer (score 0):

Descobri

Fiz uma operação ternaria:

```
$dataTimeLast = $user->LastLogonDate>0 ? date('d/m/Y', strtotime($user->LastLogonDate)) : '';
```

e no PHP ficou assim:

```
<td><span><?php echo date('Ymd', strtotime($user->LastLogonDate)); ?></span><?php echo $dataTimeLast; ?></td>
```